# Accessing bloomFilter datatype created in Redis4.0 from scala

Tags: scala, redis, bigdata, bloom-filter

I have used Rebloom package and created bloomfilter as a data structure in redis4.0 Now i want to store and check values in that bloomfilter from my scala code. I am using scala-redis library for the redis scala connection.

i can store and check the values in redis set,list etc. as this are the data structures of redis. but now i want to access the redis bloom filter in same way as i access other data structures of redis.

Can anyone help me on this...
 or any other approach to create scala bloom filter backed by redis is also accepted.
Thank You.

Comment: https://oss.redislabs.com/redisbloom/Java_Client/